# Nested calls can lead to uninitialized arguments in C?

Tags: c, unsafe

Is `len` correctly initialized and safe in `set_array` call?

```
void object_copy (Object* self, Object* obj) {
    int len;
    object_set_array (self, object_get_array (obj, &len), len);
}
```

If not, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - there's no defined order of evaluation for arguments to a function call.

Even though the call to `object_get_array()` has to occur before the call to `object_set_array()`, the value that the compiler calculates and passes to `object_set_array()` for the `len` parameter can be done before the compiler makes the  call to `object_get_array()`.

I'm not sure what the 2nd parameter to the `object_set_array()` call is intended to be - maybe you wanted to use the comma operator:

```
void object_foo (Object* self, Object* obj) {
    int len;

    object_set_array (self, (object_get_array (obj, &len), len));
}
```

Which would work, but is confusing and something I wouldn't recommend.

I think what you want is:

```
void object_foo (Object* self, Object* obj) {
    int len;

    object_get_array (obj, &len);  // get the length from obj

    object_set_array (self, len)); // set the len for self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The third parameter of `object_set_array()` might be evaluated and pushed onto the stack before the second parameter (`object_get_array()`) is evaluated.

Probably you want

```
void object_copy (Object* self, Object* obj) {
    int len;
    /* I'm just guessing as to the return type */
    Object *pObj = object_get_array(obj, &len); 
    object_set_array (self, pObj, len);
}
```

Comment: @sth: yeah, I knew I was skirting the calling-convention issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `len` by value into the `object_set_array()` call before it is initialized.  So that is wrong and a good compiler will warn about that.  The variable will contain a random value, so the code will not crash, but it won't do what you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

If `object_get_array` fails, then `len` may not get initialized. It would be better call `object_get_array` first before calling `object_set_array`, in that way you could test if the call worked or not.

Here's an example code, note that I do not know what `object_get_array` returns so I have used a `void *` to make it easier to explain:

```
void *obj;
obj = object_get_array(obj, &len);
if (obj != NULL) object_set_array(self, obj, len);
```

The code that you have written is dangerous, but resorting to shortcuts like this could lead you to think that `object_set_array` has failed and not `object_get_array`. You have to judge for yourself if it will fail or not, I always assume the code fails so that I can put safeguards in place, your approach will be different, certain shortcuts are ok, this one isn't!

Even though, C code is executed from left to right, in the order of how the expression is evaluated (depends on the compiler and compiled code), if the function worked, then yes, `len` would be initialized, but it is not safe.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
ARRAY object_get_array (Object* self, int* len);
void object_set_array (Object* self, ARRAY array, const int* len);

// ...

void object_copy (Object* self, Object* obj) {
    int len;
    object_set_array (self, object_get_array (obj, &len), &len);
}
```

because the call to `object_get_array()` will always be evaluated before the call to `object_set_array()`, at which point `len` will have been set to the correct value.

Comment: that was the object of my question, and it looks like other answers are clear about evaluation order being undefined in C for arguments. Can you provide more information to confirm your answer?

Comment: The point is that `len` is passed by reference after it is assigned, rather than by value (possibly before it is assigned.)